# Process Folders In Sequential Order (1, 2, 3, 4, etc) - Zipping Folders

Tags: vbscript, zip, 7zip, sequential

In the below code, I'm looping through a directory of folder and zipping each folder based on the folders named. I'd like to zip in order 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. The current process is zipping the folders with 1 in them. 1, 10, 100, 1000, 1001, 1002, etc.

Folder examples: Test1, Test2, Test3...Test100, Test101, Test102, etc

Is there a way to process in sequential order?

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const ForAppending = 2
Dim objFSO:Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

LogFile = "C:\Test\Test_Zip.log"
Dim objLogFile:Set objLogFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(logfile, 2, True)

objStartFolder = "C:\Test\PDFs\Processed"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
'objLogFile.Write objFolder.Path ''START FOLDER
'objLogFile.Writeline
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
    'objLogFile.Write objFile.Name ''WRITE LOGFILE
    'objLogFile.Writeline
Next


ShowSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
    For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
        'objLogFile.Write Subfolder.Path
        'objLogFile.Writeline
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
        Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
        For Each objFile in colFiles
            'objLogFile.Write objFile
            'objLogFile.Writeline
            strCommand = """c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"" a -tzip """ & Folder & "\" & Subfolder.Name & ".zip"" """ & objFile.Path & """"
                        oShell.Run strCommand, 0 ''HIDES COMMAND PROMPT
                        objLogFile.Write objFile.Name & ": " & Folder & "\" & Subfolder.Name & ".zip"
                        objLogFile.Writeline
                        wscript.sleep 1500

        Next

        ShowSubFolders Subfolder
    Next
End Sub

objLogFile.Close
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Is it skipping the files that don't have a "1"? I guess the current order is alphabetical. If you want something else (e.g. `test2` before `test10`) you'll have to write your own sorting algorithm. Alternative is to add leading zero's to your file names. If you do that you can simply sort them alphabetically.

Comment: Yeah I thought about padding in zeros, which would likely eliminate the issues. All files eventually processed, just not in sequential order. Like test1,test10,test11,test12,test13,test14,test15,test16,test17,test18,test19,test100,test101,test102, etc. Not a huge deal breaker though. The tough part is the folder and filenames can't included any leading zeros.